# Как сделать активный слайд вторым в Swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По задумке нужно чтобы активный слайд был вторым но первый был в поле видимости. Можно ли так сделать? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: Конечно можно :)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)